# How to access processing.js 'width' and 'height' outside processing.js functions

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, processing.js

I've recently made the leap from using Khan Academy's processing.js environment to the real deal and am getting a little confused.

I have a simple processing.js program that basically draws a circle, and I want the size of this circle to be determined by the width of the canvas.

If I print the width within a processing.js function, like setup, I'm shown the correct 500px width. Unfortunately, whenever I try to access the width property outside of a processing.js function, it shows the default 100px size, even though the canvas itself is 500px wide.

I think I might be using a fairly ugly mix of processing and javascript, which could be the root of my problems. Your help would be much appreciated!

**Processing.js**

```
///* PROCESSING.JS SETUP *///
void setup() {
    size(500, 500);
    println(width); // WORKS! :)
}

println(width); // DOESN'T WORK... :(

///* GLOBAL VARIABLES *///
var moleculeQuantity = 1;

///* OBJECT CONSTUCTORS *///
var Molecule = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
};

Molecule.prototype.draw = function() {
    noStroke();
    fill(88, 91, 183);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 70, 70);

    fill(225, 227, 228);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 40, 40);
};

// Fill array with molecule objects
var molecules = [];
for (var i = 0; i < moleculeQuantity; i++) {
    molecules[i] = new Molecule(200, 100);
}

///* DRAW FUNCTION *///
void draw() {
    background(225, 227, 228);
    molecules[0].draw();
}
```

Comment: write `var width;` somewhere in the global scope?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but @Kevin has pointed out why this won't necessarily work below. The globally declared width still remains undefined until the setup function is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with mixing Processing and JavaScript, and it has nothing to do with asynchronous execution. It's much simpler than that.

Think of the order your code executes in. Anything outside of a method will execute **before** your `setup()` function is called. In your case, that means you're accessing the `width` variable before you've changed it by calling the `size()` function.

You have to change your code so that your code is triggered after `setup()` is called. The simplest way to do that is to just move your code to the end of your `setup()` function, or into a function that's called after `setup()`, such as the `draw()` or event methods.

You might think that because your function call is below the `setup()` function in your code that the `setup()` call happens first, but it doesn't. You've simply **defined** the `setup()` function- it hasn't been called (by Processing) yet! Try moving any code that's outside of a function to the top of your sketch to make it more obvious:

```
println(width); // this happens first, so width is still 100

void setup() {
    size(500, 500);
    println(width); //now that size() has been called, the width is 500
}
```

**Edit:** I'll try to explain the order of events. Here is what happens when you load a page that contains a Processing.js sketch:

1. The page is loaded.
2. Processing.js itself is loaded.
3. Processing.js compiles your Processing code into JavaScript code.
4. Your code (which is now JavaScript code) is **loaded**. Functions like `setup()` and `draw()` are **defined** at this step, but not called yet. Code outside of your functions is called. This is when you see `100` being printed out.
5. Processing.js calls the `setup()` function that was defined in step 4. This is when the `width` is set.
6. Processing.js starts calling the `draw()` function 60 times per second.

As for where you should place your variables and functions, that completely depends on what you want to do with them. But you might place a variable's **declaration** at the top of your sketch and its **initialization** inside the `setup()` function. That way you can access its value anywhere, but you know it won't be set until `setup()` has run. Something like this:

```
float middleX;

void setup(){
   size(500, 500);
   middleX = width/2;
}

void draw(){
   background(0);
   ellipse(middleX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that makes a lot of sense. I thought processing.js compiled into javascript before running, and I presumed that the first thing it would need to do is execute the setup function. Are you saying that processing.js generally executes its functions after hoisting my javascript, or does it just so happen that the setup function is executed later? In this case, where should I place my constructors and global variables when they will require 'width'? Wouldn't placing them in the setup function localise their scope? Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: Also, I just checked the processing.js documentation, and it says that setup() is called once when the program is started. Now I'm very confused. If setup() is called when the program is started, why doesn't it immediately set the width variable?

Comment: @curzmg Check out my edit and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Great edit - that's cleared up the order of operations for me. I'm sure there's a perfectly good reason for it, but it seems a little frustrating that such crucial variables aren't available from the start. Oh well, I'm sure I can figure something out. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @curzmg They aren't available at start for the same reason that `mouseX` and `mouseY` aren't available before you move the mouse into the window. It doesn't make sense to ask Processing for the mouse position before the mouse has a position, and it doesn't make sense to ask Processing for the size before the sketch has a size. Any problems caused by this can be resolved by simply moving the initialization of whatever variables to the end of the `setup()` function.

Comment: I understand the mouse situation, but isn't it processing that's setting the size anyway? I mean, it wouldn't make sense to do anything at all on the canvas until you knew its size. The trouble is that I can't initialise the variables inside the setup function because they still won't be set until after my javascript has run. That means none of my objects could use those variables. Alternatively, I could have setup call a function, but then any objects in that function would be limited to that scope and therefore useless to draw().

Comment: I guess I'll just have to reset all my object properties in the setup function, which is basically the same thing. It just seems ugly somehow. Btw, I'm sure my frustration stems from my lack of understanding - it'll all make sense once I have a better grasp of processing!

Comment: @curzmg Processing isn't setting `width` and `height` - you are! That's why Processing can't know their values ahead of time. And yes, I think you're misunderstanding how scope works- why can't you just set the values of whatever you want from your `setup()` function, like in my example? That absolutely does **not** limit their scope to the `settings()` function, as long as the **declaration** is at the sketch level, like my example. Why are you running JavaScript before the `setup()` function is called anyway? Just call it from `setup()` itself instead.